# How to map many custom tables per user to a real DB?

Tags: database-design

There is a web application that supposes every user has multiple custom tables. Presented as tables with typed columns (number, short text, file or reference to another table row). Something like a light-weight Excel, but with typed columns.

**What is the best way to store the data in a real DB?**

One possible solution: create a giant table with fields Int1, Int2 .. Int32, String1, String2 .. String32 and so on, presuming that there would never be a table with more than 32 columns of the same type. All users data will go in the table and tables themselves will be stored in a table 'Tables'.

All my engineer's guts are against such approach, because it doesn't feel 'pure'. Users never heard of 'Normalization' and if they keep their data in tables at all, they *will* tend to adding another column every time another dictionary table should be used. So limit of 32 columns per type could be too hard for them. On the other hand, the most of columns will be empty, because typical simple tables will have not more than 5-10 columns in total.

Another solution: just keep the real DB up with the virtual one, and every time a user creates a table for her purposes do the same in the real DB. It would end up in thousand tables in the DB which is not a typical case, so a performance penalty is possible.

Maybe, noSQL is the answer?

Comment: If you want to use "One Big Table" to store a bunch of otherwise unrelated smaller tables, then 1) that's not a relational design, so it's not surprising that you're having trouble getting it into SQL, and 2) the general way to do it in SQL is whats called EAV or "*Entity-Attribute-Value*" design, for which Google will return tons of information.  And finally 3), EAV works but is arguably, *still* not relational for this application.

Comment: @RBarryYoung I've seen the 'One Big Table' pattern in the SharePoint DB (aka WSS DB) used for the same purpose. And I was shocked a bit. Thank you for EAV, will see what's this. If you convert the comment into an answer, I'll mark it with the 'Up' button at least.

Comment: @RBarryYoung Yes, EAV seems to be exactly what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use "One Big Table" to store a bunch of otherwise unrelated smaller tables, then

1. that's not a relational design, so it's not surprising that you're having trouble getting it into SQL, and
2. the general way to do it in SQL is what's called **EAV** or "*Entity-Attribute-Value*" design, for which Google will return tons of information. And finally,
3. **EAV** works but is arguably, *still* not relational for this application.

Comment: Have found that sparse columns from MS SQL Server is a good alternative. Not sure they're supported in other RDBMSs.